# Initialize GLSL layout with glEnableVertexAttribArray

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I want to pass arrays of vertices, UV's and normals to the shader and transform them using MVP matrix, so I wrote a simple shader program:

```
#version 330 core
//Vertex shader
layout(location=0)in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location=1)in vec2 vertexUV;
out vec2 UV;

uniform mat4 MVP;

void main(){
    gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);
    UV = vertexUV;
}

#version 330
//Fragment Shader
in vec2 UV;
out vec3 color;
uniform sampler2D color_texture;

void main(void) {
    color = texture(color_texture, UV).rgb;
}
```

Then I needed to pass an array of vertices, which is being initialized like that:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &vertices[0], model_usage);
```

Same with UV's and normals, the type is still GL_ARRAY_BUFFER for them.

Then a draw loop:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        for (Model* mdl : baseShader->getModels()) {

            glUseProgram(baseShader->getShaderProgram());

            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mdl->getTextureBuffer());
            glUniform1i(texture_location, 0);

            glm::mat4 mvp = RootEngine->projection_matrix * RootEngine->view_matrix * mdl->getModelMatrix();
            glUniformMatrix4fv(baseShader->getMVPlocation(), 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0]);

            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mdl->getVertexBuffer());
            glVertexAttribPointer(0,  3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

            glEnableVertexAttribArray(1); // Matches layout (location = 1)
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mdl->getUVsBuffer());
            glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, mdl->getVertices()->size());

            glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

        }

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(RootEngine->getMainWindow());
```

BaseShader and Model are my own classes which do a simple initialization and VBO handling.

The problem is nothing actually being rendered. I tried to add `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);`

and

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
...
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
```

But still nothing. When I don't use layout and pass the data with glVertexPointer everything seems to work fine.

UPDATE 1: I found out what prevents vertices from being rendered. It's uniform variable in the VertexShader. If it's being removed the vertices are being rendered, but then there is no way to pass a matrix to the shader.

Comment: EnableVertexAttribArray shouldn't be called after the buffer definition?

Comment: OpenGL documentation doesn't say anything about the call order. And since OpenGL is a big stack machine it would be logical to select layout element first and then bind the buffer, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You of course can use matrices as uniforms. If your object disappears when you use MVP matrix, your matrix just transforms your object out of the viewing volume.

Comment: glLoadIdentity() does not do something useful for your program since you are using your own matrices in shader...

Comment: @Victor.Palyvoda, the program used to work with gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix, but since it is deprecated in OpenGL 3 I reworked the code and forgot about glLoadIdentity(). Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just passed the wrong texture, so the model was colored black and thus invisible. Thanks everybody for your answers.